# For loop only loops 5 times

Tags: apex, loop

I have a vf page that creates 10 dummy Attachments so it can display on the page. When I go to save the attachments I"m looping through the list and removing the bad ones. The problem is it's only looping 5 times and then gives the error in test:

> List Index out of bounds: 5

I can't figure out why it's stopping, only halfway.

Method:

```
public PageReference saveAttachments()
{
    Integer startSize = attachments.size();

    for(Integer i = 0; i < startSize; i++)
    {
        if(
            attachments[i].Body == null ||
            attachments[i].Name == null
        )
        {
            attachments.remove(i);
        }
    }

    if(attachments.size() > 0)
    {
        try {
            insert attachments;
            return goBack();
        } catch (DMLException ex)
        {
            ApexPages.addMessages(ex);
        }
    }
    return null;  
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are removing items while iterating over them.

When you get to 5 you have removed 5 items and this the size is only 5. When you get to six it breaks.

It is not advisable in general to remove items while iterating over them but if you do there are several ways to do it.

This is one, use a collection to insert and not remove items from the initial collection:

```
public PageReference saveAttachments()
{
    Integer startSize = attachments.size();
    Attachment[] toInsert = new Attachment[]{};

    for(Integer i = 0; i < startSize; i++)
    {
        if(
            attachments[i].Body != null &&
            attachments[i].Name != null
        )
        {
            toInsert.add(attachments[i];
        }
    }

    try {
        insert toInsert;
        return goBack();
    } catch (DMLException ex){
        ApexPages.addMessages(ex);
    }
    return null;  
}
```

you can also step backwards if you want to remove items from the collection:

```
public PageReference saveAttachments()
{
    Integer startSize = attachments.size();

    for(Integer i = startSize -1; i >=0; i--)
    {
        if(
            attachments[i].Body == null ||
            attachments[i].Name == null
        )
        {
            attachments.remove(i);
        }
    }

    if(attachments != null) //no need to check size, depending on code can remove this if the collection is never null. Since you did not check when you get the size above you can most likely remove this if
    {
        try {
            insert attachments;
            return goBack();
        } catch (DMLException ex)
        {
            ApexPages.addMessages(ex);
        }
    }
    return null;  
}
```

Among various other ways some of which are better patterns which I am sure someone will post as well

Comment: Ohhhh, I understand this.

Comment: Really good answer, I prefer the backwards counting because it doesn't use the extra array.

Comment: For your backwards loop, you should use _for (Integer i = startSize -1;_

Comment: @HeartWare you are correct sir. Updated

Answer (score 3):

You are removing elements from the list, so the list gets smaller. By the time you get to i=5, there are only 5 elements left in the list so the final index is 4.